# How to pass value from a child component that is based on react-tag

Tags: reactjs

I would like to make a child pass an array value to a parent component.

The parent component has an array in its state.
I want to add it to array by using sampleTags. However, I don't know how to pass the array from the child component.
Should I migrate all handles of sampleTag to ParentComponent rather than looking for a way?

```
class ParentComponet extends Component {
    state = {
        tags: []
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.profileUpdate(this.state);
    }
    render() {
        const { auth, authError ,profile} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                    <sampleTags onTags = {this.state.tags}/>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Submit</button>
                        <div className="red-text center">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
const sampleTags = ({onTags}) => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([{ id: "Thailand", text: "Thailand" },{ id: "India", text: "India" }]);


  const handleDelete = (i) => {
    const  dtags  = tags;
    setTags(dtags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i));
    onTags = tags;
  };

  const handleAddition = (tag) => {
    setTags([...tags, tag]);
    onTags = tags;
  };

  const handleDrag = (tag, currPos, newPos) => {
    const tagsh = [...tags];
    const newTags = tagsh.slice();

    newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
    newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);

    setTags(newTags);
    onTags = tags;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTags
        tags={tags}
        suggestions={suggestions}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        handleAddition={handleAddition}
        handleDrag={handleDrag}
        delimiters={delimiters}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default sampleTags;
```

Comment: you can use `redux` to save the `array` in `store` and access it in your `parent` using `mapStateToProps` ...eg. https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples

Comment: You have to handle your data in the parent and pass parent function to manage your data as child props, or maybe using ref.